# Java: How to create a directory in a zip using java.nio.file.FileSystem

Tags: java, nio, zip

I've followed what [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html) has told me but I can't get it to work. I want it so that in my test.zip a folder called "new" will be in there. Whenever I run the code below it gives a `FileAlreadyExistsException` and only creates an empty zip file.

```
    Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
    env.put("create", "true");
    Path path = Paths.get("test.zip");
    URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + path.toUri());
    try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env)) {
        Path nf = fs.getPath("new/");
        Files.createDirectory(path);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Fixed title spelling, removed filesystems tag since this is pretaining to the java library FileSystem and not general filesystems

Answer (score 7):

Because `Files.createDirectory()` states in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...))

> throws `FileAlreadyExistsException` - if dir exists but is not a
>   directory (optional specific exception)

you need to check if the folder already exits:

```
try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env)) {
    Path nf = fs.getPath("new");
    if (Files.notExists(nf)) {
        Files.createDirectory(nf);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried java.util.zip.ZipEntry ?

```
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("test.zip");
ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(f));
zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("new/"));
```

Comment: The reason why I want to use FileSystem is because you can append to the zip file using it, as far as I know, ZipFile and ZipEntry cannot do that.

Comment: well there is [zipfilesystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) that works with FileSystem, but it was introduced in java7

Comment: The question was not about how to do it in general but specifically with the new nio API